# Calling functions in parent object (i.e. list)

Tags: r, scoping

I have a dynamically created list, so I cannot refer to the object by name:

```
my_list <- list()
my_list$math <- function(x, y) {
  z <- x * y
  z
}
my_list$execute <- function() {

  z <- my_list$math(12,6) + 18 # <- how to access the parent object `my_list`?
  z

}
```

How do I access `math` when I don't know the parents (`my_list`) name?

Answer (score 1):

**1) proto** The proto package can do that except it is based on environments 
rather than lists.  If `p` is a proto object then `p$f()` invokes the `f` inserting `p` as its first argument.  `p$f(x)` would pass `p` as the first argument and `x` as the second, etc.

```
library(proto)
p <- proto(
  math = function(., x, y) x * y,
  execute = function(.) .$math(12, 6) + 18
)
p$execute()
## 90
```

**1a)** The following would also work because `math` does not need to know which proto object it is being called from; however, the first way shown is preferred since it allows all functions to be overridden -- see the proto vignette for more on this if it is of interest.  Another disadvantage of this relative to (1) is that we cannot use `p2$math(x, y)` since that would insert `p2` into `math`'s first argument but we still could invoke it using `with(p2, math(x, y))` .

```
library(proto)
p2 <- proto(
  math = function(x, y) x * y,
  execute = function(.) math(12, 6) + 18
)
p2$execute()
## 90
```

**2) Base R lists** It is not as clean to do it from first principles using base R and lists but the basic idea is to pass the list as the first argument.  In this case we could omit the `self` in the `math` argument list or you may want to standarize on having all functions use `self` to make it easier to remember.

```
my_list <- list(
  math = function(self, x, y) x * y,
  execute = function(self) self$math(self, 12, 6) + 18
)

my_list$execute(my_list)
## [1] 90
```

**3) Base R environments** To do it based on base R and environments create the functions in a local environment and then pass them out in a list:

```
myobj <- local({
  math = function(x, y) x * y
  execute = function() math(12, 6) + 18
  list(math = math, execute = execute)
})
myobj$execute()
## [1] 90
```

**3a)** A variation of (3) is to use a function's body to hold the environment.  Try `demo("scoping")` for more on this.

```
genobj <- function() {
  math = function(x, y) x * y
  execute = function() math(12, 6) + 18
  list(math = math, execute = execute)
}
myobj <- genobj()
myobj$execute()
## [1] 90
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option using `eval` and provide *my_list* as the environment in which expression is to be evaluated

```
my_list <- list()
my_list$math <- function(x, y) {
    z <- x * y
    z
}
my_list$execute <- function() {
    z <- eval(quote(math(12,6)), envir = my_list) + 18 
    z
}

my_list$execute()
[1] 90
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with `dplyr`, `magrittr` and [piping](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/pipe-r-tutorial)?

In this workflow 'accessing' the parents name is not necessary because it is implicitly carried, like this:

```r
var1 <- c('A','B')
var2 <- c(1,2)
df <- data.frame(var1,var2)

# Workflow without dplyr

result <- function(df$var2)


# Workflow with dplyr and magrittr pipping

library(dplyr)

df %$%
    mean(var2)
```

So this might be helpful to you, as you could simply pipe from your dynamic list creation into the function.

Please note that it depends on your function which pipe is appropriate:

```r
df %>% function(var2) # Basic pipe in dplyr, it pushes a data frame into the next function. Works only with functions that accept a data frame as a key argument (which are all dplyr functions)

df %$% function(var2) # Explosion pipe from magrittr, it exposes all variables of the data frame from the LHS to the function in the RHS, I assume this is more useful to you
```

Maybe this approach helps you